# Javascript and Chart.JS - issue with getting unique text in 3 donut hole charts - same text showing for all 3 donut holes

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I'm a bit of a Chart.JS noob and I'm nearly done with a data dashboard.  I'm not huge on adding titles and rather add descriptors in more obscure spots.  I have a row of 3 donut charts, all with different data and fields. I want to insert unique text inside the donut hole for all three of these.  For example, I would want one to say "Sources", one to say "Funder" and one say "Search Method" - all inside a respective donut hole.  I came across some code that will add text smack in the center, however it's huge and only lets me insert one text string. Unfortunately, all three donut holes show the same text inside.  I know the method I used to attempt to include text in the donut holes is wrong, but I wanted to demonstrate that I tried. Any help is appreciated.

The CodePen is here: https://codepen.io/tenebris_silentio/pen/ExPBLNo

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Portfolio Review Overview</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <title>VARC Portfolio - Actual Access versus Perceived Access</title>


        <head>
            <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
            <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
        </head>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row my-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <h4>Review Overview</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2">
                <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 34rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 34rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chBar"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut1"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut2"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut3"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>

    <script>
    /* chart.js chart examples */

    // chart colors
    var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

    /* large line chart */
    var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
    var chartData = {
      labels: ["Sept 19", "Oct 19", "Nov 19", "Dec 19", "Jan 20", "Feb 20", "Mar 20", "Apr 20", "May 20", "Jun 20", "Jul 20"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [20, 14, 44, 33, 22, 33, 10, 40, 30, 20, 11],
        label: '# of Projects Identified by Month',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: colors[0],
        borderWidth: 4,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
      }
    //   {
    //     data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
    //     backgroundColor: colors[3],
    //     borderColor: colors[1],
    //     borderWidth: 4,
    //     pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
    //   }
      ]
    };
     if (chLine) {
      new Chart(chLine, {
      type: 'line',
      data: chartData,
      options: {
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: '# of Projects Identified by Month'
          },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: '# of Projects Identified'
      }
    }],
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false
            }
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        responsive: true
      }
      });
    }

    /* bar chart */
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chBar');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: ['Proportion of Coded Projects'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Coded Projects',
        data: [70],
        backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
      },
      {
        label: 'Remaining Projects',
        data: [170],
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,1),
       },
     ]
    },
   options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
    }
   }
   });

    /* 3 donut charts */
    var donutOptions = {
      cutoutPercentage: 85,
      legend: {position:'bottom', padding:5, labels: {pointStyle:'circle', usePointStyle:true}}
    };

    // donut 1
    var chDonutData1 = {
        labels: ['Web-based search', 'Other'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,2),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [75, 25]
          }
        ]
    };

    var chDonut1 = document.getElementById("chDonut1");
    if (chDonut1) {
      new Chart(chDonut1, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData1,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = "Project Sources",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
  });

    // donut 2
    var chDonutData2 = {
        labels: ['AHRQ', 'NIH', 'Privately Funded', 'Locally Funded'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,6),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [40, 20, 10, 10]
          }
        ]
    };
    var chDonut2 = document.getElementById("chDonut2");
    if (chDonut2) {
      new Chart(chDonut2, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData2,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    // donut 3
    var chDonutData3 = {
        labels: [
          'NIH ExPORTER', 'Clinicaltrials.gpv', 'Other'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [21, 45, 55]
          }
        ]
    };
    var chDonut3 = document.getElementById("chDonut3");
    if (chDonut3) {
      new Chart(chDonut3, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData3,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    /* 3 line charts */
    var lineOptions = {
        legend:{display:true},
        tooltips:{interest:false,bodyFontSize:11,titleFontSize:11},
        scales:{
            xAxes:[
                {
                    ticks:{
                        display:false
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display:false,
                        drawBorder:false
                    }
                }
            ],
            yAxes:[{display:false}]
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 6,
                right: 6,
                top: 4,
                bottom: 6
            }
        }
    };


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.pluginService.register({beforeDraw:...}) is called multiple times, and there is the core part for what you're asking. You can check which chart you're drawing and set the text depending by this. Following whole code (it's simply yours plus some lines):

```
<script>
/* chart.js chart examples */

// chart colors
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

/* large line chart */
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels: ["Sept 19", "Oct 19", "Nov 19", "Dec 19", "Jan 20", "Feb 20", "Mar 20", "Apr 20", "May 20", "Jun 20", "Jul 20"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [20, 14, 44, 33, 22, 33, 10, 40, 30, 20, 11],
    label: '# of Projects Identified by Month',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: colors[0],
    borderWidth: 4,
    pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
  }
  //   {
  //     data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
  //     backgroundColor: colors[3],
  //     borderColor: colors[1],
  //     borderWidth: 4,
  //     pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
  //   }
  ]
};
if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: '# of Projects Identified by Month'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: '# of Projects Identified'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      responsive: true
    }
  });
}

/* bar chart */
var ctx = document.getElementById('chBar');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Proportion of Coded Projects'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Coded Projects',
        data: [70],
        backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
      },
      {
        label: 'Remaining Projects',
        data: [170],
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,1),
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
    }
  }
});

/* 3 donut charts */
var donutOptions = {
  cutoutPercentage: 85,
  legend: {position:'bottom', padding:5, labels: {pointStyle:'circle', usePointStyle:true}}
};

// donut 1
var chDonutData1 = {
    labels: ['Web-based search', 'Other'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,2),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [75, 25]
      }
    ]
  };
  
  var chDonut1 = document.getElementById("chDonut1");
  if (chDonut1) {
    new Chart(chDonut1, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData1,
      options: donutOptions
    });
  }
  
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var width = chart.chart.width,
      height = chart.chart.height,
      ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      
      ctx.restore();
      var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      
      var text = "";
      
      switch(chart.chart.canvas.id){
        case "chDonut1":
           text = "Sources";
           break;
        case "chDonut2":
           text = "Funder";
           break;
        case "chDonut3":
           text = "Search Method";
           break;
      }
      
      var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
      textY = height / 2;
      
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
    }
  });
  
  // donut 2
  var chDonutData2 = {
    labels: ['AHRQ', 'NIH', 'Privately Funded', 'Locally Funded'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,6),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [40, 20, 10, 10]
      }
    ]
  };
  var chDonut2 = document.getElementById("chDonut2");
  if (chDonut2) {
    new Chart(chDonut2, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData2,
      options: donutOptions
    });
  }
  
  // donut 3
  var chDonutData3 = {
    labels: [
      'NIH ExPORTER', 'Clinicaltrials.gpv', 'Other'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
          borderWidth: 0,
          data: [21, 45, 55]
        }
      ]
    };
    var chDonut3 = document.getElementById("chDonut3");
    if (chDonut3) {
      new Chart(chDonut3, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: chDonutData3,
        options: donutOptions
      });
    }
    
    /* 3 line charts */
    var lineOptions = {
      legend:{display:true},
      tooltips:{interest:false,bodyFontSize:11,titleFontSize:11},
      scales:{
        xAxes:[
            {
                ticks:{
                    display:false
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display:false,
                    drawBorder:false
                  }
                }
              ],
              yAxes:[{display:false}]
            },
            layout: {
              padding: {
                left: 6,
                right: 6,
                top: 4,
                bottom: 6
              }
            }
          };
          
          
          </script>
```

Alternatively, you can check either by chart.id (it will be 1 for the first chart, 2 for the second etc...)

Comment: Clearly, I am missing something.  I gave it a try.  Would you mind posting the entire code? Likely something I'm overlooking.